# Arbitrary number of parameter assignment with template class

Tags: c++, c++11, object-pooling

I would like to implement a simple template ObjectPool kind of class.
It has a fixed size vector as a member variable, which elements' are default initialized upon creation.
That's done already and works fine.

The question is what is the best way to assign new elements to the member vector?

I implemented *add_old_way* member function, which is able to add any type of data to the ObjectPool, and works fine.
My only problem is that i create an extra object which i pass to that function, and inside, i just throw it away after assignment. Waste of resources, if we are talking about giant classes.

How should i implement *add_new_way* function which is able to take arbitrary parameters and assign them individually to vector element?

Please note ObjectPool is templated so any kind of class can be it's type, not just Bar or Matrix2x2 as in the example below.

I don't eve now the key words here to look it up on the internet, neither if it's possible at all.

Thank you!

```
template <class T>
class ObjectPool
{
    vector<T> mObjects;

    ObjectPool() : mObjects(size)
    {
    }

    //that's what i could come up with to add an object to the object pool
    void add_old_way(const T& object)
    {
        ...
        mObjects[nextFreeIndex] = object;
        ...
    }

    //desired way of adding object
    void add_new_way(...)
    {
        mObjects[nextFreeIndex].param1 = param1;
        mObjects[nextFreeIndex].param2 = param2;
        ...
        mObjects[nextFreeIndex].paramN = paramN;
    }

};

class Bar
{
    Bar(int x, string s)
    {
        mX = x;
        mS = s;
    }

    int mX;
    string mS;
};


int main()
{
    ObjectPool<Bar> v;
    ObjectPool<Matrix2x2> v;

    //that's what i could come up with
    v.add_old_way(cBar(1,"asdf"));
    v.add_old_way(cMatrix2x2(1,2,3,4));

    //desired way of adding object
    v.add_new_way(1,"asdf");
    v.add_new_way(1,2,3,4);

}
```

Comment: You want this to behave like `emplace_back` from `std::vector`?

Comment: @Justin I looked it up just now, was not aware of that. Yes, something like that, even looked at the source, but just don't get it how these arbitrary number of parameters are get handled, and assigned individually.

Comment: OT: if the vector is of fixed size, what about an `std::array`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize move semantics and perfect forwarding to make the assignment cheap:

```
template <typename... Args>
void add_new_way(Args&&... args)
{
    mObjects[nextFreeIndex] = T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9650f492259fe225)

Since the object being assigned from is a temporary, the move-assignment operator of the object being assigned to will be invoked if it exists.  This will let the object transfer ownership of any expensive-to-copy resources from the temporary to the object in the pool.

For further reading, take a look at this question: [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

Answer (score 1):

If using C++11 and above, to implement your `add_new_way` method, you can use variadic template parameters and forwarding:

```
template <typename... Args>
void add_new_way(Args... args) {
  mObjects.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then calling code can do:

```
v.add_new_way(arg1, arg2, ..., argN);
```

Comment: Variadic template and forwarding ... would never figure out they called like that, thanks! I looked up the && operator and i guess i should utilize that too, so solution mark goes to @Miles Budnek